# VSTO Outlook: How to know which placement is finally chosen for the Popup

Tags: .net, wpf, wpf-controls, outlook-addin, office-addins

I know you can define the position of a Popup by setting the Placement property to Custom. Then you can create and assign a CustomPopupPlacementCallback delegate in order to position the Popup as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/how-to-specify-a-custom-popup-position?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).

I would like to know if there is a way or some event to handle to know which position is finally chosen from the defined. Is is possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

In the code of your callback (event handler) you may save the chosen option for the popup window and expose it further using standard .net mechanisms like properties and etc.

Anyway, you just need to set the parent window handle to display the popup window in Outlook correctly. The `Inspector` or `Explorer` class implements the `IOleWindow` interface which allows retrieving the parent window handle:

```
/// <summary>
/// Implemented and used by containers and objects to obtain window handles
/// and manage context-sensitive help.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// The IOleWindow interface provides methods that allow an application to obtain
/// the handle to the various windows that participate in in-place activation,
/// and also to enter and exit context-sensitive help mode.
/// </remarks>
[ComImport]
[Guid("00000114-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")]
[InterfaceType (ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface IOleWindow
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the window handle to one of the windows participating in in-place activation
    /// (frame, document, parent, or in-place object window).
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="phwnd">Pointer to where to return the window handle.</param>
    void GetWindow (out IntPtr phwnd) ;

    /// <summary>
    /// Determines whether context-sensitive help mode should be entered during an
    /// in-place activation session.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="fEnterMode"><c>true</c> if help mode should be entered;
    /// <c>false</c> if it should be exited.</param>
    void ContextSensitiveHelp ([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)] bool fEnterMode) ;
}
```

So, you can use the `GetWindow` method for getting the handle and using it for displaying popups correctly.